# Is it possible to see what's processing on the GPU?

Tags: windows, windows-10, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, monitoring

Is there a way to see what specifically is processing on the GPU, and namely which program running on the GPU is currently holding its reins?

"Process Monitor" on Windows shows what's happening behind the curtains as far as filesystem, registry, network, process activity, profiling, stack, etc. Obviously a GPU isn't doing all these things, I'm just wondering along the lines of "*Of the five processes currently open and running on the GPU, program X is currently having Y activity processed on the GPU*," or the like.

I know in Task Manager you can see what programs are processing on the GPU, but that only shows percentages, not what is actually being processed.

For reference, this is on Windows 10 Pro with an Nvidia GPU.